# Excel Pivot in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pivot-table

Does there exist any php/mysql framework/product that helps you to build same kind of data tables as known from pivot tables in Excel?

Comment: they are called 'Pivot Tables' or Cross-Tabulation in mysql as well; google has lots of resource, i don't know what you are specify after

Comment: If you can run something like Mondrian against your MySQL database, then you can use a library like PHPOLAP

Comment: PHPExcel is the most advanced, and it doesn't support Pivot Tables yet.

Answer (score 3):

Is an old question but, there is an excelent article about it. 
    http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-excelpivotphp/
basically, create your pivot in excel, save as xml, you may have 2 files: one with the data and another with the pivot structure. Then create the data xml with php at anytime and open the pivot table. Sweet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the Pivot Table components. E.g. here's a showcase of connecting one to php/mysql simply via CSV
http://www.flexmonster.com/blog-connect-database